# How to give a value to a column based on other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet.

I have many values going down columns 1,2,3 (1000) and I want to have a new column, 5, which returns the following value depending on what is in the other cells:

if column 4 is Y, return N

Comment: `=IF(D2,"Going",IF(AND(A2,B2,NOT(C2)),"Away",IF(AND(NOT(A4),NOT(B4),C4),"Soon")))`

Comment: @BigBen Why don't you post your solution as an answer. At least we can vote for a good answer then and don't have to choose between a semi good and a worse one?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - done, yeah I should really stop posting answers in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Just some straightfoward logic with `IF`, `AND`, and `NOT`:

```
=IF(D2,"Going",IF(AND(A2,B2,NOT(C2)),"Away",IF(AND(NOT(A4),NOT(B4),C4),"Soon")))
```

[image]

Note that this formula will return `FALSE` for any possibilities besides the three you outlined. If that's not desired, you can add `""` for example as the last option: `...,"Soon",""`.

Comment: Ctrl+G: go to E1000. Then Ctrl+Shift+ up arrow. Then Ctrl+D.

Comment: Or simple perform a double mouse click on the small square in the right bottom of your active cell (here `E2`)!

Answer (score 0):

This is you can achieve with simple if formula -

```
IF(D2=TRUE, "GOING", IF(AND(A2=TRUE,B2=TRUE,C3=FALSE),"AWAY",IF(AND(A2=FALSE,B2=FALSE,C2=TRUE),"SOON")))
```

Note - if cells has value as TRUE FALSE only then use it in formula without "" else you should use "" for other text.

Comment: Please change `C3` to `C2`

Comment: Highly recommend to change `"TRUE"` to `TRUE`, same for `FALSE` that is no text in the cells and therefore not a string, that is a boolean. You have a lot of unnecessary implicit type conversions going on here!

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula @D2

```
IF(D2=TRUE,"GOING",IF(AND(A2=TRUE,B2=TRUE,C2=FALSE),"AWAY",IF(AND(A2=FALSE,B2=FALSE,C2=TRUE),"SOON","NA")))
```